# 'Refresh DataTable' not an option for me in DataSet designer

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I need to get my PK back to me after doing an update on my DataTableAdapter but the DataSet Designer does not give me the option, I attached a screenshot.

How do I get around this?

[image]

Comment: Your Db+Provider combo does not support this.

Comment: you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No, you could write an answer yourself, and state what database (version) etc this is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henk pointed out above in the comments to my question, the issue is with my database version.

I was trying to use this tool against SQL Server 2000, which it works great for except the 'Refresh the Data table' option which is not support.

So instead I wrote my own stored procedure that returns my scope_identity like I needed.